# UIButton text not visible when animating button image

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uilabel

I have to toggle two images (with animation) on UIButton, but that hides my label behind image on UIButton. Hence I added subview of UILabel to it and that is also not showing. I even tried to bring the subview to the front but that also doesn't work.

```
let options = [option_1, option_2, option_6]
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

imageArray.append( UIImage(named: "light_button.png" )! )
imageArray.append( UIImage(named: "dark_button.png" )! )

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.option_1.frame.width, height: self.option_1.frame.width))
label.text = "HEY"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
option_1.addSubview(label)
option_1.bringSubview(toFront: label)

for option in options{
    option?.setImage( UIImage(named: "green_button.png")!, for: .normal)

    option?.imageView!.animationImages = imageArray
    option?.imageView!.animationImages = imageArray

    option?.setTitle("TEST TEXT", for: .normal) //Even this don't work

    option?.imageView!.animationDuration = 2.35
    option?.imageView!.startAnimating()   
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What have you added in options array?

Comment: @ishika those are the UIButtons.

Comment: I meant to ask have you created outlets or created buttons programmatically?

Comment: @ishika I have created UIButton with outlets. And there are 6 such buttons. Where I want to toggle the image on button to highlight and unhighlight 3 buttons. Which are added into array (Options)

Comment: you really dont to manage all these arrays and all..You can manage all these states via storyboard and just have to change its state as per requirement. Rest all things will show up as set in the state configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to give you a simple solution.
Take a button and adjust its selected and default state from storyboard itself. For example select the default state of a button and give it a title and and image from the IBInspector.Then repeat the same process for selected state as well choosing the state configurations. 
[image]

Then you can also manage the image and title of the button as shown in the image.[image]

Then at at last you can manage your code as given below:

```
       class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonObj: UIButton!
   var stop = false
    var timer:Timer?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       // toggleButtons()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.toggleButtons), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
    }

    func toggleButtons(){
        if stop{
            timer?.invalidate()
        }else{
            buttonObj.toggleSelection()
        }


    }

      @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        //Once you click the button stop will become true and hence your timer will invalidate
        stop = true
    }
}
    //MARK:-******** UIButtonExtension  ***********
extension UIButton {
    func toggleSelection() {
        self.selected = self.selected ? false : true
    }
}
```

You can also choose between various animation types as per your requirement.

Comment: As I move into the view from another view. I want the view to start the buttons like blinking bulb. (Toggling 2 images.) Is that possible with the above solution?

Comment: I want the loop of toggle to continue until there is a click. on any of the options.

Comment: Oh this works like a charm. I have made necessary changes to meet my requirements.

Comment: Hey..Sorry for the delay..You can use timer and for toggling as updated in the code..Moreover, can stop on click of the button

Comment: This is just what I my requirements needed. Thanks for the great update. This solves a big time problem. Had been up looking for the solution since 2 days.

Comment: this toggleSelection() once activated do not allow button to be clicked. Is there any thing required to be done?

Comment: Button do not take touch event

Comment: What do you want to on the click? Then i can explain

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c774ab3fa8f9974df863d735225a1f40

Please check here. I have summarized the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set image as background image ?

option?.setBackgroundImage( UIImage(named: "green_button.png")!, for: .normal)

Answer (score 0):

You may set the background images for UIButton for normal and selected state and then animate when toggling between states(toggle selected and not selected on tap of button)

Comment: But I couldn't figure out any way to animate the background images. 
Could you mind. Providing and code skeleton for it. Thanks in advance.